# Creating 3D animated map video

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, mapbox, video-processing

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/query-terrain-elevation/

I did the same animation in the link using react native. Now I want to export this to a video.

I want user to click a button then everything to be done at backend. For example, send post request to
/api/createMapVideo and request body contains the coordinates of MarkerViews, polyLines etc... and use theese data to create animated map video then store it on cloud and after doing all of that send the url of video in the cloud as response. Like relive app's 3d videos.

How can I achieve this functionality? I want to create animated map video on backend. Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I did come across [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/debug/video-export.html) on Github perhaps it helps as it's about EXPORTING THE CANVAS TO VIDEO and you can read more about this in this [blog entry](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/building-cinematic-route-animations-with-mapboxgl) from a developer at Mapbox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).